# Expand 1-n Oblivious Transfer to retreave only an item I, for which permissions exist

Tags: oblivious-transfer

To my understanding in a 1-n Oblivious Transfer the Sender has some Values $X_1...X_N$ and the receiver wants to retreave some $X_I$, with $1 \le I \le N$.

Can one now somehow guarantee, that the Receiver has the permissions to retreive said $I$? Assuming every receiver has some rights to receive exactly one certain $I$, and no other Receiver has them.
I think keeping the possible $I$ values secret would be insecure and not an option.

Comment: You mean [oblivious transfer with access control](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/529)?

Comment: One could use [Oblivious Signature-Based Envelopes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=28C10A61FEB570ACDF55AFB87244116C?doi=10.1.1.74.7431&rep=rep1&type=pdf). $\;$